# Generating Pythagorean Triples with either leg <= some limit

Tags: python, math

Right now I calculate (primitive) Pythagorean Triples in this way

```
def generateTriples(limit):
    for n in xrange(1, limit):
        if (n**2 + (n+1)**2 > limit): 
            break
        for m in xrange(n+1, limit, 2):
            if (n**2 + m**2 > limit): 
                break
            if (gcd(n, m) > 1): 
                continue
            yield (m**2 - n**2, 2*m*n, m**2 + n**2)
```

But what this does is output all triples where all legs fall less than or equal to the limit. For example:

```
for triple in generateTriples(25):
    print triple
'''
(3, 4, 5)
(15, 8, 17)
(5, 12, 13)
(7, 24, 25)
'''
```

But what I'd like to do is change it around so that I am only limiting the legs. The hypotenuse can be as large as it wants -- I just want the min(leg1, leg2) to be less than or equal to the limit.

I'm also aiming to generate nonprimitives, which means scaling by k on all terms (also such that min(leg1, leg2) is <=the limit, but I worry that I will get duplicates this way.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should take a look at my edit. The original version wouldn't find all triples; my new version that wraps yours is fairly efficient and will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function determines the maximum possible hypoteneuse that could be paired with a leg in a perfect triple, then uses your function to actually search for the triples:

```
from fractions import gcd

def generateTriples(limit):
    for n in xrange(1, limit):
        if (n**2 + (n+1)**2 > limit):
            break
        for m in xrange(n+1, limit, 2):
            if (n**2 + m**2 > limit):
                break
            if (gcd(n, m) > 1):
                continue
            yield (m**2 - n**2, 2*m*n, m**2 + n**2)

def generate_triples_limit_leg(leg):
    limit = leg**2 / 2 + 1

    for triple in generateTriples(limit):
        if min(triple) <= leg:
            yield triple

print list(generate_triples_limit_leg(i))
```

This version doesn't find all triples, but works directly on the min leg:

```
def generate_triples(limit):
    # for each number up to the limit
    # Python ranges don't include the max number
    # start from 4 because 1 and 2 are invalid
    # and 3 and 4 give the same triplet
    for i in range(4, limit + 1):
        # if i is odd
        if i % 2:
            # the two larger legs are the integers
            # above and below half of the square of the smallest leg
            # // is floor division
            big = i**2 // 2
            yield i, big, big + 1
        else:
            # the two other legs are the integers
            # above and below half of the smallest leg squared
            big = (i // 2)**2
            yield i, big - 1, big + 1


print list(generate_triples(10))
# [(3, 4, 5), (5, 12, 13), (6, 8, 10),  (7, 24, 25), 
#             (8, 15, 17), (9, 40, 41), (10, 24, 26)]
```

Comment: interesting... do you have a source for this code snippet and/or algorithm?

Comment: @JasonS No. I'm sure it's known, but I discovered it independently in geometry class my freshman year of high school. As soon as I saw this question it popped into my head.

Comment: ok, cool -- so you're finding all the triples where the longer side + hypotenuse differ by 1 or 2. This appears to be Euclid's method (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulas_for_generating_Pythagorean_triples) Unfortunately that does *not* find all primitive Pythagorean triples: it misses others where the gap is larger than two, like (20,21,29) and (30,80,89).

Comment: @JasonS Ahh. Ok, then wrapping his existing function intelligently is the way to go. I'll take a stab at that.

Comment: @JasonS OK, I wrote a wrapper that finds the theoretical maximum hypoteneuse, then uses AOAOne's function to generate the actual triples.

Comment: @agf: `ints = iter(xrange(leg, 2**31-1))`. Otherwise you get `TypeError: xrange object is not an iterator`. And you could improve the finding of max `i`. Theoretically, maximum `i` is the minimum value that gives `i**2 - (i-1)**2 >= leg**2` which then reduces to `i = (leg**2)/2 + 1`.

Comment: @Avaris The `iter` is in my code, I don't know why / how it got cut out. I didn't worry about that step so long as it was correct enough, since it's so cheap compared to the finding of the triples. Thanks, though, I'll make the changes.